# Casting to 8 bytes variable takes only 4 bytes

Tags: visual-c++

I have structure that contains two fields:

```
struct ggg {
    unsigned long long int a;
    unsigned int b;
};
```

Field `a` should be 8 bytes long, while `b` one is 4 bytes long.

Trying to cast it to array of bytes:

```
        unsigned char c[8 + 4] = { 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
                                   0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, };
        ggg* g = (ggg *)c ; 
        char tt[1024];
        sprintf(tt, "a=%d b=%d ", g->a, g->b);
```

Got result in `tt` string :

```
 a=1 b=2
```

Looks like while casting `a` takes only 4 bytes instead of 8. Why?

Comment: That's a risky game, the struct is actually 16 bytes long.  4 bytes need to be added to pad the struct so the long long stays aligned.  But it fails first on the wrong format specifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not casting but your `sprintf` format specifiers. You are using `%d` which means `signed int`, which typically is 4 bytes.

Try changing the format string to `"a=%llu b=%u"` and you are more likely to get the expected output.

Comment: I should add that casting structs like that is not generally portable, and results may vary across different compilers or platform bitness (32/64).

Comment: Formatting fixed the error. I can assume bad data in  `a=%d` , but why `b` starts in the middle of `a` while formatting `b=%d`